# I deleted sites-available and sites-enabled but my website is still being served from somewhere

Tags: apache

I have my 2 projects in the `/var/www` folder - `html` and `test`.

I then purposely deleted everything in `sites-available` and `sites-enabled` fully expecting to get some sort of Apache error, but instead the project from the `html` folder gets served. So I can't figure out where is the virtual host conf file that specifies that the project in folder `html` should be the one served.

Comment: Did you restart Apache after deleting the configuration?

Comment: @larsks Yeah, I'm having trouble with creating subdomains using virtual hosts but I'm failing hard so I decided to delete the 000-default.conf file and create everything from scratch.